# Tallying strings in column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a query with two columns, `country` and `individuals`. Country is a list of countries  `individuals` is the total number of `employeeid` that match each `country`. I've messed around with join clauses but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: You can start by including some table structure, sample data, and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the total number of employees per country, then here it is:

```
SELECT C.COUNTRY,
    INDIVIDUALS = SUM(E.EMPLOYEE)
FROM COUNTRIES C
  INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E
    ON E.COUNTRY_ID = C.COUNTRY_ID
GROUP BY E.COUNTRY_ID
```

I assumed that `COUNTRIES` and `EMPLOYEES` are your tables.

Comment: This is not valid SQLite syntax.

Comment: @CL.I'm using **SQL Server 2008 and 2012**. However, I haven't tried it in SQLite.